# What mongodb version can I use with mongoid 2?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm currently working in a pretty old project. The current mongodb version is 2.6.x and I am locked with mongoid 2.x with the moped driver. Our database is in serious pain and I suspect it is time for an upgrade but I'm not sure about what database version I can use with the old mongoid driver.

Mongoid is such a hassle to upgrade with all the breaking changes and the rails version dependency I can only upgrade to version 3. If I do all the work of upgrading mongoid I would have liked it to be to a more recent version.

How can I find which database versions the old mongoid 2.x driver supports?

Answer (score 0):

you have to be more specific about the version you use. even minor versions require different MongoDB versions. [check this changelog](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).